# Summarise data by two grouping variables

Tags: python, r

I have a large csv recorded as below.

```
name             score          year
team_a           4              2005
team_b           6              2005
team_a           2              2005
team_c           7              2005
team_d           3              2005
team_d           4              2005

team_a           2              2006
team_b           4              2006
team_b           3              2006
team_c           4              2006
team_c           2              2006
team_d           1              2006
team_e           5              2006
```

I would like to perform a downsample as below (add total scores of every year and have the recorded instead)

```
name           total_score    year
team_a         6              2005
team_b         6              2005
team_c         7              2005
team_d         7              2005

team_a         2              2006
team_b         7              2006
team_c         6              2006
team_d         1              2006
team_e         5              2006
```

Thoughts on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: `help(aggregate)`

Comment: Okay, what's going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60339263/9494044)?

Comment: Same as I commented on [a very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60339263/9494044) today (your classmate?), it's best if you can show what you've tried so far, and narrow it down to 1 language. Some quick research on summing a value by a group should get you lots of SO posts like the one I flagged above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in csv format here is a base R solution:

```
scores = read.csv("scores.csv")
result = aggregate(data=scores, score ~ name+year, FUN=sum)
colnames(result)[3] = "total_score"
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is Python solution. First please refer to pandas manual, for example (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) then try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
df = df.groupby(["name","year"]).sum().reset_index()
```

However if file is very large, chunking method may be useful, see: [how to read only a chunk of csv file fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473327/how-to-read-only-a-chunk-of-csv-file-fast)

Comment: Doesn't change the code fundamentally, but they want the sum, not mean

Comment: My mistake, already fixed the answer, thx :-)

Answer (score 2):

In `R` and `tidyverse` terms
this would be a summarization of the scores by the groups given by `name`
and `year`.

First lets generate your example data.

```r
team_score_year_df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~name,~score,~year,
  "team_a", 4, 2005,
  "team_b", 6, 2005,
  "team_a", 2, 2005,
  "team_c", 7, 2005,
  "team_d", 3, 2005,
  "team_d", 4, 2005,
  "team_a", 2, 2006,
  "team_b", 4, 2006,
  "team_b", 3, 2006,
  "team_c", 4, 2006,
  "team_c", 2, 2006,
  "team_d", 1, 2006,
  "team_e", 5, 2006
  )
```

Now we use `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarise()` to achieve your
desired result.

```r
library(dplyr)

team_score_year_df %>% 
  group_by(name, year) %>% 
  summarise(total_score = sum(score)) %>% 
  select(name, total_score, year) # In case order of columns is important.
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [5]
#>   name   total_score  year
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 team_a           6  2005
#> 2 team_a           2  2006
#> 3 team_b           6  2005
#> 4 team_b           7  2006
#> 5 team_c           7  2005
#> 6 team_c           6  2006
#> 7 team_d           7  2005
#> 8 team_d           1  2006
#> 9 team_e           5  2006
```

Edit: Base R solution

As G5W points out in his comment, `stats::aggregate()` can do this as well.

```r
result_df <- aggregate(
  team_score_year_df$score,
  list(name = team_score_year_df$name,
       year = team_score_year_df$year),
  sum
)

names(result_df)[3] <- "total_score"

result_df[c("name", "total_score", "year")]
#>     name total_score year
#> 1 team_a           6 2005
#> 2 team_b           6 2005
#> 3 team_c           7 2005
#> 4 team_d           7 2005
#> 5 team_a           2 2006
#> 6 team_b           7 2006
#> 7 team_c           6 2006
#> 8 team_d           1 2006
#> 9 team_e           5 2006
```